# Null pointer exception occasionally occurs when kettle executes jobs concurrently

Tags: java, kettle

pentaho-version: 8.3.0.0-371

There is a probability of a null pointer problem during the parallel execution of jobs with Kettle, leading to process exit.
This problem occurs when kettle executes the job in parallel, but there is no problem when executing the job serially.

Job description：Multiple work nodes are parallelized after a conversion node. There is no dependency between each work node, but the variables in the conversion node will be obtained. Multiple work nodes are executed to the success node and end. The process can be viewed by clicking "Click to view kettle job"

[Click to view kettle job](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oeN2F.png)

```
Caused by: org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleException: 
Unexpected error occurred while launching entry [成功.0]
 at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:748)
 at org.pentaho.di.job.Job$1.run (Job.java:804)
 at org.pentaho.di.job.Job.access$000 (Job.java:121)
 at org.pentaho.di.job.Job.execute (Job.java:827)
 at org.pentaho.di.job.Job.execute (Job.java:632)
 at org.pentaho.di.base.AbstractMeta.disposeEmbeddedMetastoreProvider (AbstractMeta.java:2054)
 at org.pentaho.di.core.vfs.KettleVFS.closeEmbeddedFileSystem (KettleVFS.java:545)
 at org.pentaho.di.core.vfs.ConcurrentFileSystemManager.closeEmbeddedFileSystem (ConcurrentFileSystemManager.java:192)
 at org.pentaho.big.data.impl.vfs.hdfs.nc.NamedClusterProvider.closeFileSystem (NamedClusterProvider.java:196)
 at Proxyc5a58d92_3c85_4859_80e8_ab5b48556ae0.getExplicitMetastore (null:-1)
 at Proxyf7ed1ece_9270_4b74_90cb_3dc57fc39287.getExplicitMetastore (null:-1)
 at org.pentaho.osgi.metastore.locator.api.impl.MetastoreLocatorImpl.getExplicitMetastore (MetastoreLocatorImpl.java:39)
 at org.pentaho.osgi.blueprint.collection.utils.ServiceMap.getItem (ServiceMap.java:35)
    at org.pentaho.di.job.Job.execute(Job.java:830)
    at org.pentaho.di.job.Job.access$000(Job.java:121)
    at org.pentaho.di.job.Job$1.run(Job.java:804)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.pentaho.osgi.blueprint.collection.utils.ServiceMap.getItem(ServiceMap.java:35)
    at org.pentaho.osgi.metastore.locator.api.impl.MetastoreLocatorImpl.getExplicitMetastore(MetastoreLocatorImpl.java:39)
    at Proxyf7ed1ece_9270_4b74_90cb_3dc57fc39287.getExplicitMetastore(Unknown Source)
    at Proxyc5a58d92_3c85_4859_80e8_ab5b48556ae0.getExplicitMetastore(Unknown Source)
    at org.pentaho.big.data.impl.vfs.hdfs.nc.NamedClusterProvider.closeFileSystem(NamedClusterProvider.java:196)
    at org.pentaho.di.core.vfs.ConcurrentFileSystemManager.closeEmbeddedFileSystem(ConcurrentFileSystemManager.java:192)
    at org.pentaho.di.core.vfs.KettleVFS.closeEmbeddedFileSystem(KettleVFS.java:545)
    at org.pentaho.di.base.AbstractMeta.disposeEmbeddedMetastoreProvider(AbstractMeta.java:2054)
    at org.pentaho.di.job.Job.execute(Job.java:632)
    at org.pentaho.di.job.Job.execute(Job.java:827)
    ... 3 more
2023/09/10 14:03:29 - Kitchen - Finished!
2023/09/10 14:03:29 - Kitchen - ERROR (version 8.3.0.0-371, build 8.3.0.0-371 from 2019-06-11 11.09.08 by buildguy) : Finished with errors
2023/09/10 14:03:29 - Kitchen - Start=2023/08/31 09:55:14.915, Stop=2023/09/10 14:03:29.946
2023/09/10 14:03:29 - Kitchen - Processing ended after 10 days, 4 hours, 8 minutes and 15 seconds (878895 seconds total).
```

Comment: Which version of pentaho are you using? Also, is there a dependency between the two parallel jobs. It seems by your question, either one of the job is dependent on the other (hence working sequentially) and not in parallel. I would suggest debugging the code on step at a time.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: pentaho-version：8.3.0.0-371，Multiple work nodes are parallelized after a conversion node. There is no dependency between each work node, but the variables in the conversion node will be obtained. Multiple work nodes are executed to the success node and end. The process can be viewed by clicking "Click to view kettle job"

Comment: It could be that you are running out of memory when you launch so many transformations at the same time, you could monitor resources in your server/machine when you launch the job, and if not enough memory is the answer, you can either give more memory to the machine executing the transformations, or break the job in two or three so you have enough memory. I have broken a job into fewer parallel executions executing transformations serially when I have run into this problem, even if all the transformations could be executed in parallel theorically.